# Ionic post request

Tags: typescript, post, ionic-framework

This code below makes a post request to a server but i can't see the response in the console, despite i can see that it does the request in the server log.

```
 postRequest() {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let postParams = {
      username: 'username',
      password: 'password',
    }

    this.http.post("serverurl", postParams, options)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data['_body']);
       }, error => {
        console.log(error);// Error getting the data
      });
  }
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Do you get an error or anything like that? Nothing gets logged in response?

Comment: I only get `console.log: [object Object]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution! I've split the code:

**Provider**

```
  makeLogin(email: string, password: string) 
  {       
      let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
      urlSearchParams.append('username', email);
      urlSearchParams.append('password', password);
      let body = urlSearchParams.toString()

      var headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

      return this.http
          .post('https://classevivaapi.herokuapp.com/voti', body, { headers: headers })
          .map(response => response.json())
  }
```

**Ionic page**

```
    postRequest() {
      var email = 'andreademasi80@gmail.com';
      var password = 'Andrea99';

      this.api.makeLogin(email, password)
          .subscribe((response) => {
              alert(response);
          }, (error) => {
              alert(error);
          });
    }
```

Also i had to modify my API in order to allow Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)

Answer (score 0):

Try to log

```
console.log(data);
console.log(data.json());
console.log(data.text());
```

instead of

```
console.log(data['_body']);
```

Comment: I only get `console.log: [object Object]`

Comment: Yes, all of them

Comment: What kind of data returns your backend ?

Comment: `2017-10-31T17:29:28.975272+00:00 app[web.1]: JustAnIp - - [31/Oct/2017 17:29:28] "POST /voti HTTP/1.1" 400 -
2017-10-31T17:29:28.973889+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/voti" host=serverurl request_id=9573ba40-9f77-4617-b933-3e61f47103b8 fwd="93.40.194.134" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=400 bytes=341 protocol=https`